# Why are SQL fields not visible?

Tags: python, mysql, django, crm

I created a CRM Application and while running the code in localhost using local database. All the fields are visible but when I deployed the django app and used the Postgre or MySQL. The leads are not visible.

```
`views.py:-

from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.contrib import messages
from .forms import *
from .models import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required,user_passes_test
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
```

```
# users_in_group1 = Group.objects.get(name="MARKETING").user_set.all()
# users_in_group2 = Group.objects.get(name="TECHNICAL").user_set.all()
```

```
@csrf_exempt
def technicalregister_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TechnicalSignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Authenticate and login
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            technical_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='TECHNICAL')
            technical_group[0].user_set.add(user)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You Have Successfully Registered! Welcome!")
            return render(request, 'adminhome.html')
    else:
        form = TechnicalSignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'technicalregister.html', {'form':form})

    return render(request, 'technicalregister.html', {'form':form})

@csrf_exempt
def register_user(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            # Authenticate and login
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password1']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            marketing_group = Group.objects.get_or_create(name='MARKETING')
            marketing_group[0].user_set.add(user)
            login(request, user)
            messages.success(request, "You Have Successfully Registered! Welcome!")
            return render(request, 'adminhome.html')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()
        return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

    return render(request, 'register.html', {'form':form})

def is_marketing(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='MARKETING').exists()

def is_technical(user):
    return user.groups.filter(name='TECHNICAL').exists()

@csrf_exempt
def home(request):
    users_in_group1 = Group.objects.get(name="MARKETING").user_set.all()
    users_in_group2 = Group.objects.get(name="TECHNICAL").user_set.all()
    #leads = Lead.objects.all()
    # Check to see if logging in
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        # Authenticate
        user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
        if user is not None:
#           login(request, user)
#           messages.success(request, "you have been logged in")
#           return redirect('adminhome')
            if user in users_in_group1:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged In!")
                return render(request, 'marketinghome.html')
            elif user in users_in_group2:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged In!")
                return render(request, 'technicalhome.html')
            else:
                login(request, user)
                messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged In!")
                return render(request, 'adminhome.html')
        else:
            messages.success(request, "There Was An Error Logging In, Please Try Again...")
            return render(request, 'home.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_technical)
def technicalhome(request):
    lead = Lead.objects.all()
    leads=[]
    for l in lead:
        if l.status == "CONVERTED" or l.status == "COLD":
            leads.append(l)
    return render(request, 'technicalhome.html', {'leads':leads})

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_marketing)
def marketinghome(request):
    leads = Lead.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'marketinghome.html', {'leads':leads})

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
def adminhome(request):
    leads = Lead.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'adminhome.html', {'leads':leads})

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
def logout_user(request):
    logout(request)
    messages.success(request, "You Have Been Logged Out...")
    return render(request,'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
def customer_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Look Up Records
        customer_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'lead.html', {'customer_lead':customer_lead})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View That Page...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt    
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_technical)
def technical_update_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Look Up Records
        customer_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'technical_update_lead.html', {'customer_lead':customer_lead})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View That Page...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt    
@login_required()
def adminlead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        # Look Up Records
        customer_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        return render(request, 'adminlead.html', {'customer_lead':customer_lead})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To View That Page...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_marketing)
def delete_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        delete_it = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        delete_it.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Lead Deleted Successfully...")
        return render(request, 'marketinghome.html')
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To Do That...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
def admin_delete_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        delete_it = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        delete_it.delete()
        messages.success(request, "Lead Deleted Successfully...")
        return render(request, 'adminhome.html')
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In To Do That...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt    
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_marketing)
def add_lead(request):
    form = AddLeadsForm(request.POST)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                messages.success(request, "Lead Added...")
                return render(request, 'marketinghome.html')
        return render(request, 'add_lead.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_marketing)
def update_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = AddLeadsForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_lead)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Lead Has Been Updated!")
            return render(request, 'marketinghome.html')
        return render(request, 'update_lead.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')
    
@csrf_exempt
@login_required()
@user_passes_test(is_technical)
def technical_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = AddLeadsForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_lead)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Lead Has Been Updated!")
            return render(request, 'technicalhome.html')
        return render(request, 'technical_lead.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return render(request,'home.html')

@csrf_exempt
@login_required()   
def admin_update_lead(request, pk):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        current_lead = Lead.objects.get(id=pk)
        form = AddLeadsForm(request.POST or None, instance=current_lead)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request, "Lead Has Been Updated!")
            return render(request, 'adminhome.html')
        return render(request, 'admin_update_lead.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        messages.success(request, "You Must Be Logged In...")
        return render(request, 'home.html')
```

marketinghome.html:-

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}



{% if user.is_authenticated %}

{% csrf_token %}

<button>
    <nav>
        <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'add_lead' %}">Add Lead</a>
    </nav>
</button>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
  <thead class="table-dark">
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">Name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Phone</th>
      <th scope="col">Address</th>
      <th scope="col">City</th>
      <th scope="col">State</th>
      <th scope="col">Zipcode</th>
      <th scope="col">Created At</th>
      <th scope="col">Discription</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
      <th scope="col">Total Payment</th>
      <th scope="col">Payment_Status</th>
      <th scope="col">ID</th>

    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    
{% if leads %}
    {% for lead in leads %}
        
            <tr>
                <td>{{ lead.first_name }} {{ lead.last_name }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.email }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.phone }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.address }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.city }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.state }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.zipcode }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.created_at }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.discription }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.status }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.total_payment }}</td>
                <td>{{ lead.payment_status }}</td>
                <td><a href="{% url 'lead' lead.id %}">{{ lead.id }}</a></td>
            </tr>
        
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}

    
      </tbody>
    </table>





{% else %}

<div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
<h1>Login</h1>
<br/>

<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}

  <div class="mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username", placeholder="Username" required> # line 78
    
  </div><br/>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password", placeholder="Password" required> # line 82
  </div>
  <br/>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary">Login</button>

</form>



{% endif %}

{% endblock %} # line 93
```

Line 78, 82 and 93 shows "unexpected character after attribute value"

To deploy the CRM but the data isn't visible in admin, marketing or technical account but is visible in superadmin.